# python selenium element is not clickable at point even while using wait until element to be clickable

Tags: python, selenium

my function for finding the elements looks like this:

```
def find_element(val, elem=None, by=By.CLASS_NAME) -> WebElement:
    if elem is None:
        elem = driver
    element = WebDriverWait(elem, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, val)))
    return element
```

i am calling this function simply everytime i need to find the element.

```
weekday = find_element("weekday")
weekday.click()
```

there is one specific problematic button that is sometimes working and sometimes not.
it gives me this error :
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (840, 12). Other element would receive the click:

issue is that sometimes it works (when i am using bigger monitor) sometimes it doesnt, also when i run the debugger, and wait couple of seconds 10/20 then it becomes clickable. I dont understand why its not clickable when the element_to_be_clickable says that it is.

ps  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", weekday) doesnt do anything at all, tried it as well.

Comment: `find_element` takes in two parameters, one being the class of the item and the second being the name of that element class in this case 'weekday'

Comment: @iKreateCode whats your point, i wrote that code.

Comment: This means there is another item on top of the element you are trying to click.  Include the full exception in your post.  The end of it will list the element that is intercepting the click.  (That bit is important in troubleshooting...)  Could be a loading indicator, a prompt wanting user input, etc...

Comment: @pcalkins theres nothing visually over it. and i dont know how to tell selenium to avoid everything but that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by scrolling the element into middle of the page.

```
desired_y = (weekday.size['height'] / 2) + weekday.location['y']
current_y = (driver.execute_script('return window.innerHeight') / 2) + driver.execute_script(
    'return window.pageYOffset')
scroll_y_by = desired_y - current_y
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", scroll_y_by)
```

Answer (score 1):

to solve

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element
```

You should debug your code like the below:

1. Make sure the browser is launched in full screen using

   ```
   driver.maximize_window()
   ```
2. Use `ActionChains`:

   ```
   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME, ".weekday"))).click().perform()
   ```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: got this error.
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.67)
Stacktrace:

Comment: did only actionchains part of the code. and it partially helped me. basically i need to runt hat code 7 times, for each day of the week, it ran 3 times correctly, and then crashed... same error.

Comment: again, it works on all 7 days, if its on my monitor, instead of a laptop screen.

Comment: there was one syntax error here `(By.CLASS_NAME` , Now I've removed it, Please try again.